# Using Switch() VS Creating Multiple Scripts?

Tags: php, performance

Actually I have a architecture question. I want to know, should I create multiple separate scripts *(`.php` files)* for some tasks which have both relevant together and different jobs? Or should I create just one script and use `switch()` function *(of `if`-statement)* to separate them of each other?

---

Let me say an example. I have a question-and-answer *(Q&A)* website. I want to know should I create two separate scripts for *writing a question* and *writing an answer* or should I create just one script for storing both answers and questions?

In other word:

**One:** One script

```
Storing_answers_questions.php

if ($_[POST] == 'q') {
    // codes for storing a question are here
} else {
    // codes for storing a answer are here    
}
```

And then the `action` of both forms (question, answer) will be:

```
www.example.com/Storing_answers_questions.php
```

**Two:** Multiple scripts

```
Storing_answers.php

// codes for storing a answer are here

// ------------------------------------------------------------

Storing_questions.php

// codes for storing a question are here
```

And then the `action` of question-form will be:

```
Storing_questions.php
```

And answer-form will be:

```
Storing_answers.php
```

Well, which way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it doesn't fall in the performance. It's a question of maintainability.

The question now is why and how?

---

Once your codes becomes long, it will be very confusing to look at your code. It will be harder to find what you're looking for. If you have seperated and organize files, it will lessen the risk for that to happen.

> Real life scenario:
>
> You have files in your computer, There is phptest.php, jstest.js,
>   jquerytest.js, csstest.css in one folder. Isn't it easier to find if you
>   seperate them in folder.
>
> PHP->phptest.php
>
> JavaScript->jstest.js, jquerytest.js
>
> CSS->csstest.css

---

Seperated Files is also best for team project. You can assign this group to write a code for *questions* , and this group is for *answers* without stepping on their toes (*Even if you are using version controls*). They are organize.

---

And that's it, if you think this will have a very long complicated codes. Go for seperation.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the one-file style for this sort of thing would be typical, unless you have a deliberate flow in mind.